# PowerBI and nested 1:N data

Tags: powerbi, nosql

I'm trying to leverage the advantages of DocumentDB / Elastic / NoSQL for retrieving big data and to visualize it. I want to use PowerBI to do that, which is pretty good, however, I have no clue how to model a document which has a 1:N nested data field. E.g.

```
{
  name: string,
  age: int
  children: [ { name: string }... ]
}
```

In a normal case, you would flatten the table by expanding the nested values and joining them, but how does one do that when it's 1:N / A list. Is there a way to maybe extract that into it's own table?

I've been thinking about making a bridge which translates a document into data tables, but that feels like an incorrect way to go, and further proves some complications with regards to how many endpoints and queries there should be made.

I can't help but think this is a solved issue, as many places analyse and visualize large amounts of data stored in no sql. The alternative is a normalized relational database, but having millions and millions of entries in that which you analyze also seems incorrect when nosql is tuned for these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If the data 1:N, but not arbitrarily deep, you can use the [expand option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Expand-a-column-containing-a-related-table-Power-Query-d5e552be-c143-4f06-9a5e-0960bbaaf480) in the query tab. You will get one row for each instance of customer that has all the attributes of the container.

If you want to get more sophisticated, you could normalized the schema by expanding just the customer id column (assuming there is one in your data) into one table, and expanding the customer details into another one, then creating a relationship across them. That makes aggregations easier (like count of parents). You'd just load the data twice, and delete the columns you don't need.

Comment: I get your idea, but unfortunately it doesn't seem feasable for me. If I expand it to another table (which is ideally what I want), I have the problem that I cannot create the relationship, because there's no unique columns. In a document (nosql) the relation is inherently created because it's nested in the document structure - so is there a way to artificially capture this relationship 'on-the-fly' with power bi?